# How to load data in weka Instances from a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, instance, weka

I have a spark DataFrame. Now I want to do some processing using Weka. Therefore, I want to load data into Weka Instances from the DataFrame and finally return the data as a DataFrame. As the structure both the data type is different, I wondering can anybody help me with the conversion. The code snippet may look like below.

```
val df: DataFrame = data
val data: Instances = process(df)
```